# How to disable editing of certain event on ajax load

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am using FullCalendar for my event management. I am creating events from a user end and it is then approved by the admin. When an event(Dragable Event) is created by user is editable until it is not approved by admin. When event is approved I want it to be disabled i.e. user can not edit it. Here what I am using the code:

```
events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: AJAX_URL,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            start: start.format(),
            end: end.format()
        },
        success: function(doc) {
            var events = [];
            if(doc != ''){
                jQuery.map( doc, function( r ) {
                    // alert(r.status); // status is either 1 or 0

                    events.push({
                        id: r.id,
                        title: r.title,
                        start: r.start_time,
                        end: r.end_time,
                        textColor: 'black',
                        editable: (r.status) ? true : false,                                
                    });
                });
            }
            callback(events);
        }
    });
}
```

I have searched for many other solution but none of them working.

Comment: what is the actual issue?

Comment: How can I make certain event non-editable when loaded from database?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried the updateEvent [option](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/updateEvent/)? 
Something like this:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent',{
 id: r.id,
 title: r.title,
 start: r.start_time,
 end: r.end_time,
 textColor: 'black',
 editable: (r.status) ? true : false                                
});
```

Furthermore, I think there is an extra comma after editable:

> editable: (r.status) ? true : false,

I did not test it, but these are my thoughts.

I hope it helps,
Greg

Comment: Hi!
Is there any js console log?

Comment: No. Not any one

Comment: Yes. I have converted it to DATE_ISO8601 format. and it is displayed correctly on the calender

Comment: You should try the event(s) to print out to the console (what not be added), after that try to add one event via console (e.g.: copy my code with data). 
That way you can test that part. If it it works, You should check that "add" or "update" part is running with some debug log. 
I hope that way the bug will come up.